# TCP blocking socket - possibility of recv small amount of bytes in different packets

Tags: sockets, tcp, packet

If the server sends 4 bytes

```
send(sock, buffer1, 4, 0);
```

And client waits for exactly 4 bytes

```
recv(sock, buffer2, 4, 0);
```

Is there a possibility that less than 4 bytes will be written to `buffer2`?
No other `send` or `recv` was made before.

If there is no possibility, what's the maximum size of buffer that `send` can do, so that `recv` could get the same buffer size in one call.

Comment: Is your actual question _"How do I know when I have received a complete message"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster, no. I wanted to know if I can always get complete _message_.

Comment: You should always write your socket code as if was possible that only 1 byte at a time will be received. In other words, always check the return value from recv and handle a partially filled buffer as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for `recv`:

"These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred.

For TCP sockets, the return value 0 means the peer has closed its half side of the connection."

As such `recv` is *always* allowed return all of the bytes sent, fewer than the bytes sent, or none of the bytes sent.  You cannot assume anything simply because you happen to know what `send` is doing at the other end of the connection.

There is no way to guarantee that you can always get complete message.

Comment: It is only allowed to return none of the bytes sent if the socket is in non-blocking mode or an error occurs. Otherwise it must block until at least one of the bytes arrives, or EOS occurs instead.

Comment: Of course it could, and your answer doesn't make that clear. There's also a widespread belief that recv() returns zero when the peer stops sending, e.g. at the end of a message: your answer could be read to support that as well.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a "message", except what you delimit yourself.

**REPEAT**: THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS A MESSAGE.

TCP does not send messages, it sends an octet stream.

You need to send in a loop, in case there is a backlog of unacknowledged data and `send` does not use the whole buffer you passed in. You need to recv in a loop, in case the sending stack chunked it in an unexpected way. You need to delimit your messages (eg by prepending a network-endian length), so you can recover them properly.

Comment: +1 about once a day this 'TCP does not handle my multi-byte massage correctly' gets posted.  That, and 'strlen returns the wrong result for the data in my buffer', and 'printf(%s..) segfaults when trying to print my buffer'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's this possibility. In fact, recv gives you as return value the amount of bytes received.